# consolidating and Adding data to new lines to a field in a column in mysql table

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns in my table X:

```
Id      State       Type
1        NJ         Form1
1        NY         Form 2
1        TX         Form 3
```

I want to consolidate it to one column in table Y:

```
Id   FormTypes
1    NJ:Form1
     NY:Form2
     TX: Form3
```

Is this possible to achieve???

Currently I have worked out so much:

```
DECLARE @NewLine as char(2) = char(13) + char (10)

UPDATE tableY

SET FormTypes =
(
      select substring(
         (select ':'+ [State] + ':'+ Type+ @NewLine AS 'data()' 
            from tableX  
            for xml path(''))
      ,3, 255)
as "MyList"  )
```

This is giving me garbage like this:

```
NJ:Form1'&#x0D'; NY:Form2'&#x0D'; TX:Form3'&#x0D';
```

The reason for getting it in this form is due to the way it is getting read in multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     x2.id, 
     STUFF((SELECT char(10)+x1.State+':'+x1.Type FROM tableX x1 WHERE x1.id=x2.id GROUP BY x1.id for xml path(''),TYPE),1,1,'') as stype 
FROM tableX x2
GROUP BY x2.id
```

this will give you tableY form

Comment: @Nilish Tag said it was for mysql. But i think it was edited to sql server. I have edited my post

Comment: But it would still not give results in a new line.

Comment: I already had tried using '\n'. That ends up adding \n to the string: \n NJ :Form1  :(

Comment: @bitoshi.n already tried that too- it gives &#x0DNJ:Form1. This '&#x0D' is appended before everything . Same as my result on top :(

Comment: @jill  it's because `for xml path('')` . try add `,TYPE`

Comment: This didn't worked for me until after I removed `GROUP BY …` and `,TYPE`.